# How to create user profile with django-registration?

Tags: django, model, profile, django-registration

In django 1.7 I use [django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to handle user registration and I'd like to automatically create a UserProfile instance for each newly registered user.

So in models I have:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_pirate', None, {'username': self.account.user})    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.username) 

#**this line is supposed to create user profile****    
User.profile = property(lambda u:UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(username=u)[0])
```

But when I check the database no new row in userprofile_userprofile is created after a new user registration. What is wrong here? 
If the line is in wrong place, where should it be?

Comment: where have u wrritten this last line which is supposed to create user ?

Comment: just below the class as seen above.

Comment: you should put it in view, where you are handling registration part..

Comment: wonder ! .. come again .. tell how you gonna create the user ?

Comment: @vijayshanker I followed this tutorial which suggests the line should be in model.py: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/django-profile

Comment: @rajasimon the users are created using good old django-registration

Comment: i suggest you should follow django docs closely ..

Comment: Just updated the question. Could not find the answer in the DR docs. Appreciate your hints.